# "not like" in DolphinDB SQL

Tags: sql, dolphindb

```
t=table(`Gold`GoldMines`Silver`SilverMines as id, 1 2 3 4 as x);
select * from t where id not like "%Silver%";
```

It returns the following error message:

```
Function not is not a binary operator
```

Does anyone know what I can do with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesnt support `not like`. Use not as follows:

```
select * from t where not id like "%Silver%";
```